# "Рябова С.М. — инспектор". Запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какой знак лучше поставить (запятую или тире) после имен собственных при перечислении.

Например:

```
На заседании присутствовали: 
Рябова С.М. - инспектор спорта и политики;
Иванова Е.Н. - вожатая;
Петрова В.А. - начальник отдела кадров
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

*На заседании присутствовали(:) инспектор спорта и политики Рябова С.М., вожатая Иванова Е.Н., начальник отдела кадров Петрова В.А.*

**P.S.**

Двоеточие после "присутствовали" -- факультативно.

Answer (score 3):

В этом случае ставится тире, так как приложение носит пояснительный характер при однородных членах, а вместо точки с запятой ставятся просто запятые